# Analysis Services Attribute Hierarchy and Attribute Relationships

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, ssas, dimensional-modeling

Is it possible to have a attribute hierarchy where the parent doesn't always have children? If so, how is this achieved in SQL server Analysis Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - found the solution: http://iman77.blogspot.com/2009/09/handling-raggedunbalanced-hierarchies.html